# Fitnesse + WebDriver: any working solution?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, fitnesse

Could you please tell me if there were any attempts to integrate Fitnesse and Selenium WebDriver? I'm looking for something like Selenesse (https://github.com/marisaseal/selenesse), but for WebDriver, not "old" Selenium.

Thanks,
Racoon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at Xebium: http://xebia.github.io/Xebium/. It uses WebDriver instead if Se 1.0.

I do recommend that you eventually take more ownership of your driver than that. Keyword driven tests can be fast to write, but long term maintenance can be an issue. So start with Xebium, but then look into writing your own driver.